# Remove plot in kivy graph

Tags: python, kivy

When trying to remove a plot from Graph widget it gets remove properly from the `_plot_area` canvas but it doesn't get deleted until I resize the window.
I've tried calling the `_redraw` and `_redraw_all` triggers from the Graph class but they don't work.

How can I delete a plot and get it to remove directly?
An example:

```
    graph = Graph()
    plot = MeshLinePlot(mode='line_strip', color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
    plot.points = [(x / 10., sin(x / 50.)) for x in xrange(-0, 101)]
    graph.add_plot(plot)
    graph.remove_plot(plot)
```

The plot is removed but It won't disappear until I resize the window

Comment: Looks a bit like a bug...

Comment: Damn'. Anyway, is there a method to force the window to redraw in order to simulate a resize?

Comment: Jut for now I'm triggering a window resize in this way. It works, but it's like hell...
`Window._size=[Window.width,Window.height-1] 
Window._size=[Window.width,Window.height+1]`

Comment: Possibly you can try to call `ask_update` for the canvas/fbo/whatever containing the instructions.

Comment: Tried this too. No redrawing...neither calling it from the app window triggers the redraw

Comment: Managed using 
`from kivy.graphics.context import get_context`
and calling
`get_context().reload()`
Anyway the problem is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found a solution. After you call `graph.remove_plot(plot)`, put `graph._clear_buffer()`. As it seems to be a bug (it should do that automatically, if its a hidden method), so I've submitted a [pull request to the repo](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/pull/17).

Comment: That's right. It seems like the fbo's buffer couldn't get cleared.
Trying to call directly `_clear_buffer()` anyway wouldn't work: you have to rewrite it passing via the `graph._fbo` element.
Hope you don't mind, i've updated the answer

Comment: @UncleSax Calling directly worked for me (python 3)... Did you search the class dict or the instance dict?

Comment: @UncleSax Did you do `graph.__dict__` or `graph.__class__.__dict__`? Cus it's definitely in `graph.__class__.__dict__`.

Comment: My graph is an extended class from the original one of the library, so I did `graph.__dict__` as `graph.__class__.__dict__` will show me the method of the basic declaration of any class.

Comment: No it won't, unless `graph` is a class. Does `graph._clear_buffer` raise a `NameError`, or succeed, as private method begin with `__` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

These lines remove every plot in Graph:

```
for plot in self.my_graph.plots:
    self.my_graph.remove_plot(plot)
```

All example you can see at my GitHub: http://github.com/petrhomolka/Kivy-presentation

Comment: To remove multiple plots this is kind of on the right track, however you cant use a for loop as the action of removing the plot also shortens the list which causes it to stop after only removing half the plots. So you need to establish the length of the list first, then remove self.my_graph.plot[0] the appropriate number of times.